# Need help reducing the Google auth login time

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-authentication

When users login it's taking an extremely long time to get the gPlusUser.idToken....up to 7 or 8 minutes while the app is just idol waiting.

**// Google login**

```
  async googleLogin(): Promise<void> {
    try {
        console.log('before gPlus');
      const gplusUser = await this.gplus.login({
        'webClientId': environment.googleWebClientId,
        'offline': true,
        'scopes': 'profile email'
      });
        console.log('after gPlus', gplusUser);
      return await this.afAuth.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken)
      ).then((credential) => {
        console.log('getting creds', credential);
        const user: IUser = {
          uid: credential.user.uid,
          email: credential.user.email,
          displayName: credential.user.displayName,
        };

        this.updateUserData(user);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

This only began taking an extremely long time a few weeks ago.  When it was initially set up it didn't take such a long time.

It's this particular line that's taking an extremely long time:

```
      console.log('before gPlus');
      const gplusUser = await this.gplus.login({
        'webClientId': environment.googleWebClientId,
        'offline': true,
        'scopes': 'profile email'
      });
      console.log('after gPlus', gplusUser);
```

I added the console logs and it's the process of actually getting the gplususer that's taking an extremely long time.

I changed the database rules as following to no avail:

```
match /users/{userId} {
    allow read; 
    allow write;
}
```